# Is there a Vuetify equivalent for React?

Tags: javascript, framework, css, user-interface, react

I like Vuetify for Vue.js but I don't like Vue. I like React better and I'm looking for a Vuetify equivalent for React. Do you know anything like that?

Solved: Found Material UI

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Ok, I see. Well, it's for a personal project so I don't have a formal requirement document or anything like that. I literally needed something that vaguely resembles vuetify but for react. Anyways, I found it in the form of Material UI

Comment: Please [edit] your question with some more details, e.g. describing what Vuetify is and what it does. As I see you just wrote "solved": Be welcome to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) (and include with your answer details on how it meets the specifics). Thanks!